# OpenGL texture blending problems

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

I'm creating a 2d application for the iPad using OpenGL ES and having some issue drawing transparent images.

I'm using png-24 images with full transparency. I'm also changing the color of some of some textures, which are white with some areas transparent or semi-transparent. That all works fine.

When I try to set the alpha value of one of these textures, however, it's not working quite right. The colors are much too saturated, and if the alpha value = 0, i'm left with a white rather than transparent image over a light grey background. When such a transparent image is over a dark image, the dark image becomes a color similar to color of the transparent image.

I've tried a many parameter combinations of the `glTexEnvi` and `glBlendFunc` with no success.

I'm not very knowledgable about OpenGL, so if anyone has any suggestions, that would be great. Let me know if there are any details that would help.

Thanks.

---

Here is the initialization of OpenGL

```
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's input. I think I've found a solution.

The problem was that the textures had premultiplied alpha but the polygons the textures are being applied to did not. With `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` and `glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);` in place all I had to do was manually multiply the R, G, and B color values of the polygons by the alpha value so that everything is essentially using premultiplied alpha and renders consistently.

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient solution, but it seems to work perfectly so far and it was just a matter of adding a few lines of code to my image rendering class to update the color values whenever the opacity is changed.

wooo

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you told OpenGL your texture had premultiplied alpha, but it actually doesn't.

What parameters are you using for `glBlendFunc`?

[More explanation of pre-multiplied alpha](http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#%5B%5BPremultiplied%20alpha%5D%5D)

Comment: The blend function is set to `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`. I added the OpenGl initialization code to my question as well.

Comment: Apparently the blend function was actually being set to `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` somewhere else in my code. changing it to `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` fixes the issue with setting transparent colors, but it breaks the rendering of semitransparent textures and the edges of textures which turn into an awful grey.

Comment: @Anthony: You most likely have a mix of premultiplied and unmultiplied alpha in your textures.  You can either be consistent, or go around switching the `glBlendFunc`.

Comment: I think alpha premultiplication could be the problem, although the problem is consistent for all images. Is alpha premultiplication something baked into the image or is it something happening during compiling? How can I disable it?

thanks

Comment: @Anthony: It is present (or not) in the image, but it's by no means permanently fixed, you can change it easily enough at load time.

Answer (score 1):

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ALPHA);
```

This is not valid, are you checking GL errors? Check the glTexEnv man page to see the valid values:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml

GL_ALPHA is not a texture function, the valid texture functions are GL_ADD, GL_MODULATE, GL_DECAL, GL_BLEND, GL_REPLACE, and GL_COMBINE.

You might want to replace that GL_ALPHA with GL_MODULATE so you can control the texture alpha with the vertex color (glColor). This mode multiplies the texture with the vertex color.

Comment: I changed the texture environment function to `glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);`. You're right, but this doesn't solve my problem.

If I use `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` I'm having the issues with textures rendered on transparent polygons rendering strangely as I described. If I use `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` those transparencies render correctly, but semi transparent pixels in textures come out grey.

Do you have any thoughts on that? Thanks.

Comment: @Anthony Are you sure you have a alpha channel in your framebuffer? It's a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are if you're using a 24-bit PNG, you wont have the alpha channel. Try converting to a 32-bit PNG and editing the alpha channel. Alternatively you can convert from 24bit to 32bit yourself and generate the alpha channel from the image data (eg: by chroma-keying).

Then use `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` or `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);` if you want additive blending.

Comment: The alpha channels of the PNGs are working correctly. The problem is when I change the colors of the vertices the texture is mapped to. Using any opaque color works fine, but a transparent color causes these problems.

Does that make sense or am I not explaining it correctly?

Comment: are you setting anything via `glTexEnv`?