# Textures with GLKView and OpenGLES 1.1?

Tags: opengl-es, ios5, textures, glkit

I'm having trouble with getting textures to work the iOS 5 way (using GLKView) but with the old fashioned OpenGLES 1.1. I'm migrating an old 2D (sprites) style game framework. I took the stock example of OpenGL game in Xcode, and modified it to initialize the EAGLContext with kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1. I also am not trying to use the GLKTextureLoader & GLKBaseEffect, since I have my old texture loader algorithms (and base effect works with shaders). This is what I have currently in ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self setContext : [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1]];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext: [self context]];

GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
[view setContext: [self context]];
[view setDrawableDepthFormat: GLKViewDrawableDepthFormatNone];
[view setDrawableColorFormat: GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888];
[view setMultipleTouchEnabled: NO];
[self setupGL];
}
```

And in setupGL:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(0, backingWidth, 0, backingHeight, -1, 1);
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);    
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
//landscape mode
glTranslatef(backingWidth/2, backingHeight/2, 0);
glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(-backingHeight/2, -backingWidth/2, 0);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);    
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ALPHA);
```

Problems start here, I'm getting the 0x0500 error from OpenGL with that last line above. I can't really figure out, what the difference is, because this works OK in the old code (or at least if not, then it's not the source of the problem). If I use GL_MODULATE instead of GL_APLHA, then there's no GL error, but textures still do not work. This is how I load them:

```
glGenTextures(1, &textures[textureNum]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[textureNum]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

The rest is basically a call to my old renderEngine, which then sends the vertex data to OpenGL, but I suppose that should be ok, since it works in the old code.
So what do I miss here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that StackOverflow strips the greetings from the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466848/opengl-texture-blending-problems), that is: your texture has no premultiplied alpha.

Answer (score 0):

GLKit is built around OpenGL ES 2.0, not 1.1. From the iOS 5.0 release notes:

> The GLKit framework (GLKit.framework) contains a set of Objective-C
>   based utility classes that simplify the effort required to create an
>   OpenGL ES 2.0 application.

It is not intended to be used with an OpenGL ES 1.1 context, and GLKit classes should not work when used in such a context. Even for something as simple as setting up a framebuffer, 2.0 uses differently named functions than 1.1 for the same tasks.

If you intend to create an OpenGL ES 1.1 project, for whatever reason, start with a different template than the one generated by Xcode and build your own UIView backed with a CAEAGLLayer.